# How to convolve an arbitrary signal with a causal decaying exponential?

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, integration

I need to simplify the following convolution

$$x(t)\star [e^{-2t} u(t)]$$

where $u(t)$ is the unit step function. I'm very confused with this. Using the definition of convolution of continuous-time signals, I obtained

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^t {x(\tau)e^{-2(t-\tau)}u(t-\tau)}{d\tau}
$$

However, I have no idea what to do at this step. I'm stuck. Is there any property / theorem / trick that can help me simplify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you have reached what can be reached, may be the following additional line can be obtained by moving the $t$ function $e^{-2t}$ out of the integral and replacing the $u(t-\tau)$ by $1$ as:

$$
y(t) = e^{-2t} \int\limits_{-\infty}^t {x(\tau)e^{2\tau}{}d\tau}
$$

In the general case you cannot simplify it any further...

Comment: How can you replace $u(t-\tau)$ by 1? Is it always 1 from - infinity to t?

Comment: Indeed the better question is how did you determined the **upper** limit of the intgral as $t$ in the first place? i.e., $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)u(t-\tau) d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(\tau) u(t-\tau)  d\tau $$. If you reach this line then you implicitly say that $$ u(t-\tau) = \begin{cases} 1 &, \text{ for } -\infty < \tau < t \\ 0 &, \text{ for } ~~~~~ t < \tau < \infty \\ \end{cases} $$ I think now it's clear...

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. Should have thought of that. Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately it seems that there is no way x(t) can get out of the integration right?

Comment: you welcome. In the general case you cannot get $x(\tau)$ out of integration...